# Infinite while loop in TAP example

Tags: c#, asynchronous, while-loop, task-parallel-library

While researching the TAP (Task-based Asynchronous Pattern), I found this example snippet on this MSDN [webpage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873173(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
private static AsyncProducerConsumerCollection<int> m_data = …;
…
private static async  Task ConsumerAsync()
{
    while(true)
    {
        int nextItem = await m_data.Take();
        ProcessNextItem(nextItem);
    }
}
…
private static void Produce(int data)
{
    m_data.Add(data);
}
```

I don't think it makes sense as this is really an infinite loop with no way out. Am I missing something? If so, appreciate some explanation on how it works.

EDIT: I get the scope of the example, that function is trying to process items until it runs out. I also get that `Task` is same as `Task<void>`, i.e., this function doesn't have to return anything. But the fact that it has a `while(true)` bothers me, since this means this function runs forever. Does this mean it is upto the calling function to terminate the application? The details of this part is not so clear to me.

Comment: This being an infinite loop makes sense in the scope of an example, as it is simply there to depict a program that will continue to run and consume items when ever they are produced.  As far as production code, probably doing an infinite loop like this is not something that is practical.

Comment: OK, I think I got that part, but it can't be used the way they showed it, right? I would've thought the while has to be on some boolean which needs to be updated inside the loop.

Comment: You can absolutely use it the way it is shown.  As long as the thread calling ConsumerAsync() is not awaiting a return, the task will just run on a separate thread and will not block the calling thread.

Comment: Still not clear. How is it OK in the context of the program for ConsumerAsync not to ever return anything, even if the caller is not expecting a return? In this case, even if m_data is empty and there's nothing left to 'process', it still remains in the (infinite) loop. How can such a program be terminated?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to break the loop the TAP way, you can use a [CancellationTokenSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx) and call `Cancel` to break the loop.
You can read more about it both on the original [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873173(v=vs.110).aspx) you posted and on the MSDN page for `CancellationTokenSource` I added here.